# Floating a div on a google map in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a map that i have created using jquery gmap and this is the code

```
<!-- Google Maps -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
#reactive_div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 1%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  min-height:300px !important;
  min-width:500px !important;
  border:3px solid red;
}
.gm-style-mtc {
  display: none;
}
</style>    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div id="reactive_div">
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <section class="google-map-container">

                <div id="googlemaps" class="google-map google-map-full" style="padding-bottom:40%"></div>

                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&amp;sensor=true"></script>
                <script src="https://qubitgps.com/scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
                <script src="https://qubitgps.com/scripts/jquery.gmap.min.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery('#googlemaps').gMap({
                    maptype: 'ROADMAP',
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    zoom: 16,
                    markers: [
                        {
                        latitude: -1.289264,
                        longitude: 36.783180,
                        html: "Senteu Plaza",
                        popup: false,
                        }
                    ],
                });
                </script>
            </section>
            <!-- Google Maps / End -->
```

I am able to float the div like this https://jsfiddle.net/71zah2uk/ and this can be seen here https://jsfiddle.net/71zah2uk/show

My floated div cannot respond when the width of the browser changes. I want the div to at least change when i resize the browser.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot how do you want it..?

Comment: If you open the  ../show url for jsfiddle, you shall see how it looks like currently. I now want it to react when i resize the window.

Comment: what do you mean by *react*. changing size (height and / or width)? visible not visible? changing background-color? what should happen on resize?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch The div should be responsive, as in shrink or expand accordingly as the width changes.That's what i meant by react.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to just target the smallest screen possible starting from 300px

```
<div id="content">
<iframe id="gmap" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=55.886721,-4.33651&amp;spn=0.011553,0.027466&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
<div class="container overlap"><h1>Content</h1>
  <input type="text" value="hello" /><br/>
  <input type="text" value="hello" />
 </div>
  </div>

  <style>
  #gmap {
  position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;
  }
.overlap{
  top:50px !important;;
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
  background: white;
  width:300px !important;
}
  </style>
```

and this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sc82ztwu/